# certain div styles unresponsive

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvGBW/1/)

I've got a service list with a contact button below. The service list is split into a left and right side, and the contact button should be centered below. The contact button is being styled correctly, with the exception of location- it's unresponsive to attempts to move it below and center. I've tried `clear:both;` various `margin` and `padding` settings to no avail. What have I missed?

html

```
<div id="services">
        <div class="refrsh">
            <h2>service 1</h2>
            <p>lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
        </div><!-- end refrsh -->
        <div class="a-la-carte">
            <h2>service 2</h2>
            <p>lorem ipsum blah blah v 2.0</p>
        </div><!-- end a-la-carte -->
        <a class="get-started" href="#contact"><span>LET'S GET STARTED</span></a>
    </div><!-- end services -->
```

css

```
#services .refrsh {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 150px;
    width: 312px;
}

#services .refrsh p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#services .a-la-carte {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 150px;
    width: 312px;
}

#services .a-la-carte p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#services .get-started {
    clear: both;
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    padding:8px 18px;
    background:#52c0a3;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#services .get-started:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#515151;
    border: 1px solid #52c0a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working:

```
#services .get-started {
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#52c0a3;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

#services .get-started:hover {
    background:#fff;
    color:#515151;
    border: 1px solid #52c0a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#services .get-started span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:absolute;top:100px;` (or however many pixels are needed) to your button's CSS  to move it to the location you want it.  Try this:

```
    #services .get-started {
    clear: both;
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    padding:8px 18px;
    background:#52c0a3;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your button in another div with this class `<div class="footer"><div>` and add the following css:

```
#services {
    display: inline-block;
}
#services .footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

... once you have done that you can remove the `clear: both;` from your button.

A caveat here is that the screen has to be a certain width for this to work - i.e. it doesn't flow well if you re-size it. To make it wrap properly on smaller screens you will need to restructure your HTML by including a div around the lists & updating the css accordingly.